# Forward ngrok url to another domain

Tags: networking, port, portforwarding, ngrok

Can I acess the url ngrok gave me via other domain.
I want to try to get a custome domain without paying for nagrok pro.

I tried cloudflare and add CNAME record and add at the target section the url that ngrok show but It didn't work at all